# Connecting label to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created several tables in the past but I believe it's something with the way I'm doing it that Xcode doesn't like this time.

I have several xib files with a UIView inside. These together creates a slideview like snapchat.

In one of these xib files I have a UIView. In this I have a UITableView and a UITableViewCell. I have set up a prototype cell with an identifier "cell". I've set up the delegate and dataSource as I usually do.

I made a UITableViewCell class and set up the class for the prototype cell.

Here's where the trouble is:
I wanna connect my labels on the cell to the UITableViewCell class and make IBOutlets. But Xcode doesn't let me do it. It simply doesn't connect them.

Any suggestions on why I can't do it or if there's a way around??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change class of your UITableViewCell to your custom class in xib. (in utilities section,there is option called custom class)

Comment: make sure you will have to bind with UITaleviewCell not file owner in xib and also check the class of uitablview cell if you had taken custom

Comment: The custom class for UITableViewCell is already set to tableViewCell.swift which is the UITableViewCell class I've created.

Comment: Have you also taken care of the fact that @Akash has mentioned in comment, that set custom class to your Cell view not to the file owner option, this is general mistake one does.

Comment: I'll check this out.

Comment: After a little headache I understood what Kumar and Akash was telling me to do. After doing what they said it worked! Thanks guys!